# How to use channels efficiently

Tags: performance, go, optimization, benchmarking, channel

I read on [Uber's style guide](https://github.com/uber-go/guide/blob/master/style.md#channel-size-is-one-or-none) that one should use at most a channel length of 1.

Although it's clear to me that using a channel size of 100 or 1000 is very bad practice, **I was however wondering why a channel size of 10 isn't considered a valid option. I'm missing some part to get to the right conclusion**.

Below, you can follow my arguments (and counter arguments) backed by some benchmark test.

I understand that, if your both go-routines, responsible for writing or reading from this channel, would be interrupted in between sequential writings or readings to/from the channel by some other IO action, no gain is to be expected from a higher channel buffer and I agree that 1 is the best option.

But, lets say that there is no significant other go-routine switching needed apart from the implicit locking and unlocking caused by writing/reading to/from the channel. Then I would conclude the following:

Consider the amount of context switches when processing 100 values on a channel with either a channel buffer of size 1 and of 10 (GR = go-routine)

- Buffer=1: (GR1 inserts 1 value, GR2 reads 1 value) X 100 ~ 200 go-routine switches
- Buffer=10: (GR1 inserts 10 values, GR2 reads 10 values) X 10 ~ 20 go-routine switches

I did some benchmarking to prove that this actually goes faster:

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

type a struct {
    b [100]int64
}

func BenchmarkBuffer1(b *testing.B) {
    count := 0
    c := make(chan a, 1)
    go func() {

        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            c <- a{}
        }
        close(c)
    }()
    for v := range c {
        for i := range v.b {
            count += i
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkBuffer10(b *testing.B) {
    count := 0
    c := make(chan a, 10)
    go func() {

        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            c <- a{}
        }
        close(c)
    }()
    for v := range c {
        for i := range v.b {
            count += i
        }
    }
}
```

Results when comparing simple reading & writing + non-blocking processing:

```
BenchmarkBuffer1-12              5072902               266 ns/op
BenchmarkBuffer10-12             6029602               179 ns/op
PASS
BenchmarkBuffer1-12              5228782               256 ns/op
BenchmarkBuffer10-12             5392410               216 ns/op
PASS
BenchmarkBuffer1-12              4806208               287 ns/op
BenchmarkBuffer10-12             4637842               233 ns/op
PASS
```

However, if I add a sleep every 10 reads, it doesn't yield any better results.

```
import (
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func BenchmarkBuffer1WithSleep(b *testing.B) {
    count := 0
    c := make(chan int, 1)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            c <- i
        }
        close(c)
    }()
    for a := range c {
        count++
        if count%10 == 0 {
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(a) * time.Nanosecond)
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkBuffer10WithSleep(b *testing.B) {
    count := 0
    c := make(chan int, 10)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            c <- i
        }
        close(c)
    }()
    for a := range c {
        count++
        if count%10 == 0 {
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(a) * time.Nanosecond)
        }
    }
}
```

Results when adding a sleep every 10 reads:

```
BenchmarkBuffer1WithSleep-12              856886             53219 ns/op
BenchmarkBuffer10WithSleep-12             929113             56939 ns/op
```

FYI: I also did the test again with only one CPU and got the following results:

```
BenchmarkBuffer1                 5831193               207 ns/op
BenchmarkBuffer10                6226983               180 ns/op
BenchmarkBuffer1WithSleep         556635             35510 ns/op
BenchmarkBuffer10WithSleep        984472             61434 ns/op
```

Comment: An example of a problematic use of big channel buffers: you don't want sending on the channel to ever block, so you give it a big enough buffer so that it "shouldn't ever" get filled up.

Comment: A channel of size 10 is a perfectly valid option--for some operations. In fact, it's the only option for some operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely *nothing* is wrong with a channel of cap 500 e.g. if this channel is used as a semaphore.

The style guide you read recommends to not use buffered channels of let's say cap 64 "because this looks like a nice number". But this recommendation is *not* because of performance! (Btw: You microbenchmarks are useless microbenchmarks, they do not measure anything relevant.)

An unbuffered channel is some kind of synchronisation primitive and us such very much useful.

A buffered channel, well, may buffer between sender and receiver and this buffering can be problematic for *observing*, *tuning* and *debugging* the code (because creation and consumption are further decoupled). Thats why the *style* guide recommends unbuffered channels (or at most a cap of 1 as this is sometimes needed for correctness!).

It also doesn't prohibit larger buffer caps:

> Any other [than 0 or 1] size must be subject to a **high level of scrutiny**. Consider how the size is determined, what prevents the channel from filling up under load and blocking writers, and what happens when this occurs. [emph. mine]

You may use a cap of 27 if you can *explain* why 27 (and not 22 or 31) and how this will influence program *behaviour* (not only performance!) if the buffer is filled.

Most people overrate performance. Correctness, operational stability and maintainability come first. And this is what this style guide is about here.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Volker. That makes it clear.